# In angular modal, the function bind to ng-click can't access new data binded from html input

Tags: angularjs

The following code snippet is a controller used for $modal.open(), I don't know why the ok function can't get latest data changed by data binding.

```
myModule.controller('ModalCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance) {

    $scope.job = 'student'; // changed by html radio button, default is 'student'

    // called by a button with ng-click="ok()" in modal view
    $scope.ok = function() {

        // no matter what job i changed, the $scope.job always is default value 'student'
        $modalInstance.close({
            selected_job : $scope.job
        });
    };
});
```

Here is the html snippet

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="sendToModal.html">
<div>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4>Job</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="jobOption"
                    data-ng-model="job"
                    data-ng-value="student">Student
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="jobOption"
                    data-ng-model="job"
                    data-ng-value="teachch">Teacher
            </label>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="ok()">Confirm</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: can you give us the code UI too please ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with scope. Change in view:

```
data-ng-model="$parent.job"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it to the scope as a object:

$scope.job = {
name : 'student'
}

data-ng-model="job.name"

Here, I made you an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/NeUwWNYS8dfyQlrR2xfn?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't see error in this part of code...
All the binding works except the functions ?
Have you add ctrl, model etc... ?
Are you on IE8 ?

Maybe try this (it works for me):

```
// called by a button with ng-click="ok()" in modal view
    ok = function() { ... }
/*--------------------------*/
//in the view call
    onclick="ok();"
```